# Getting the parent directory inside Makefile.msc

Tags: c, nmake

I have third-party Makefile.msc (zlib) which is in a subdirectory of the source (zlib\win32). It seems you are meant to run win32/Makefile.msc directly from the source directory. However, I need to make a number of different versions, and would like the results separated out. I would also like to call nmake from a directory other than the source directory.

I tried SRCDIR = ./.. but it seems that .. is not supported. How can I get to the parent directory?

Comment: What about `SRCDIR=../` or `SRCDIR=./../`?

Comment: I think perhaps .. is just not supported. For now I am manually specifying a TOP directory, but it feels rather lame.  NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make './..//adler32.c'